# How to put a postcode look up to my cs-cart address form making an add-on?

Tags: cs-cart

I want to put a postcode look up to my cs-cart address form where customers can come and enter their postcode and I'll suggest the addresses on the basis of that.

I already have written the API, but what are the files in `cs-cart` structure that needs to be modified to put this look up in place?

Answer (score 1):

CS-Cart has a very good documentation for this (including examples & example addons). Take a look at the following webpages:

- https://docs.cs-cart.com/4.8.x/developer_guide/addons/hooking/index.html
- https://docs.cs-cart.com/4.8.x/developer_guide/addons/tutorials/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jQuery [.keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event, please be aware that are 2 fields for postal code, one for billing and one for shipping

```
$("#elm_28").keyup(function() {
  alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

[image]